# how to perform string operation in an input string and get the desired output

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have to write a shell script  to accept the product order details as string input and display the total order amount and number of order under each category.
INPUT:
`101:Redmi:Mobile:15000#102:Samsung:TV:20000#103:OnePlus:Mobile:35000#104:HP:Laptop:65000#105:Samsung:Mobile:10000#106:Samsung:TV:30000`

OUTPUT:
 `Mobile:60000:3#TV:50000:2#Laptop:65000:1`

I have to achieve this using sort,tr,cut,grep command only no sed awk should be used.

Comment: Absolutely no other command than `sort` `tr` `cut` `grep`? shell builtin are allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it is improvable, I will explain it:

```
    x="101:Redmi:Mobile:15000#102:Samsung:TV:20000#103:OnePlus:Mobile:35000#104:HP:Laptop:65000#105:Samsung:Mobile:10000#106:Samsung:TV:30000"

echo $x > origin.txt

cat origin.txt | grep -E -o ':[a-Z]+:[0-9]+' | cut -c 2- > temp.txt

categories=()
quantity=()
items=()

while IFS= read -r line
do

    category=$(echo $line | grep -E -o '[a-Z]+')
    amount=($(( $(echo $line | grep -E -o '[0-9]+') )))

    if [ "0" = "${#categories[@]}" ]
    then
        # Add new element at the end of the array
        categories+=( $category )
        quantity+=( $amount )
        items+=(1)
        
    else
    
        let in=0
        let index=0
        let i=0
        # Iterate the loop to read and print each array element
        for value in "${categories[@]}"
        do
             if [ $category = $value ]
             then
                let in=$in+1
                let index=$i
             fi
             let i=$i+1
        done
        
        
        if [ $in = 0 ]
        then
            categories+=( $category )
            quantity+=( $amount )
            items+=(1)
        else
        
            let sum=$amount+${quantity[$index]}
            quantity[$index]=$sum
            
            let newitems=${items[$index]}+1
            items[$index]=$newitems
            
        fi
        
        
   fi

done < temp.txt

let j=0
for value in "${categories[@]}"
    do
        echo -n $value
        echo -n ':'
        echo -n ${quantity[$j]}
        echo -n ':'
        echo -n ${items[$j]}
        
        let k=$j+1
        if [ $k != ${#categories[@]} ]
        then
            echo -n '#'
        fi
        
        let j=$j+1
done
```

First i save the string in x and later in origin.txt, with cat, grep and cut I obtain the string in this format inside of temp.txt:

Mobile:15000 \n
TV:20000 \n
Mobile:35000 \n
Laptop:65000 \n
Mobile:10000 \n
TV:30000

I create three arrays: categories for storage the name of the category, quantity for storage the amount of the category and items the objects of the category.

Later I read temp.txt line by line and using a simple regex I can get the name of the category and the amount of that line.

```
amount=($(( $(echo $line | grep -E -o '[0-9]+') )))
```

This is used to convert string into int.

The first if is for check if the array is empty, if it's empty we append the category, the amount and 1 object.

If is not empty we need to declare three variables:

- in, for check if the incoming category is in the array or not
- index, for storage the index of the existing category
- i, for count the times we loop

If the category already exist in the array $in is setted to 1 or higher.
If not $in still have the default value 0.

Next if in is equal to 0, means the category is new, we append to the three arrays.

If in is not equal to 0 using the index we can sum the new amount to the stored amount.

Finally when the main loop finish I print the data following the format you have mentioned.

The variable k is for not print the last "#", we compare k with the size of the array. Note that arrays start with 0 index.

Comment: @ Rafael Diaz ......Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. 
But the problem is we can not create file inside the shell script we do not have the permission to do so. 
I have changed the cat origin.txt | grep -E -o ':[a-Z]+:[0-9]+' | cut -c 2- > temp.txt to echo "$x" | tr '#' '\n' | cut -d ":" -f 3,4 and got the output as below
Mobile:15000
TV:20000
Mobile:3500
Laptop:65000
Mobile:10000
TV:30000

But after this i am not getting how to proceed further. Is there a way that we can store the above output in an array?

Comment: I tried the below code to store the output in an array, but I am getting bad substitution error.
`#!/bin/bash
x="101:Redmi:Mobile:15000#102:Samsung:TV:20000#103:OnePlus:Mobile:35000#104:HP:Laptop:65000#105:Samsung:Mobile:10000#106:Samsung:TV:30000"
array_index=0
index=0 
echo "$x"  | tr '#' '\n' | cut -d ":" -f 3-4 | while read line ;
do
category=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 1 )
amount=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 2 )
categ_array[$array_index]=$(echo "$category")
accnt_array[$array_index]=$(echo "$amount")
array_index=$(($array_index+1))
done

Answer (score 0):

The input is:

```
x="101:Redmi:Mobile:15000#102:Samsung:TV:20000#103:OnePlus:Mobile:35000#104:HP:Laptop:65000#105:Samsung:Mobile:10000#106:Samsung:TV:30000"
```

First, split records on lines:

```
tr '#' '\n' <<< "$x"
```

This gives:

```
101:Redmi:Mobile:15000
102:Samsung:TV:20000
103:OnePlus:Mobile:35000
104:HP:Laptop:65000
105:Samsung:Mobile:10000
106:Samsung:TV:30000
```

Better to keep only relevant data and store it in a variable:

```
data="$(tr '#' '\n' <<< "$x" | cut -d: -f3,4)"
echo "$data"
```

This gives:

```
Mobile:15000
TV:20000
Mobile:35000
Laptop:65000
Mobile:10000
TV:30000
```

Count how many items in each category. `sed` is used for formatting:

```
categories="$(cut -d: -f1 <<< "$data" | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//;s/ /:/')"
echo "$categories"
```

This gives:

```
1:Laptop
3:Mobile
2:TV
```

Then loop over categories to extract and compute total amount for each:

```
for i in $categories
do
  count=${i%:*}
  item=${i/*:}
  amount=$(($(grep $item <<< "$data"| cut -d: -f2 | tr '\n' '+')0))
  echo $item $amount $count
done
```

This gives:

```
Laptop 65000 1
Mobile 60000 3
TV 50000 2
```

Finally, a little bit of formatting after the `done`:

```
<...> done | tr ' \n' ':#' | sed 's/#$//' ; echo
```

This gives:

```
Laptop:65000:1#Mobile:60000:3#TV:50000:2
```